# Load dxWidget inside tab widget on PhoneJS

Tags: jquery, phonejs

How can I load a Gallery widget inside the content of a Tab widget?

I've tried putting the:

```
<div data-bind="dxGallery: { dataSource: galleryData }"></div>
```

Inside the `content` parameter of the tab widget:

```
tabs = [
  { text: L["ABOUT_ME"], icon: "user", content: '<div data-bind="dxGallery: { dataSource: galleryData }"></div>' }
```

But the widget is not displayed in this way.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow recommendations from [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q536097).

Use the [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding in your scenario. Your code should be as follows:

```
<div id="tabs" data-bind="dxTabs: { items: tabs, selectedIndex: selectedTab }"></div>
<div id="tabContent" style="height:300px;" >
        <!-- ko if: !selectedTab() -->
           <div>Tab1</div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: selectedTab() == 1 -->
           <div data-bind="dxGallery: { dataSource: galleryData  }"></div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: selectedTab() == 2 -->
           <div>Tab3</div>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

```
var viewModel = {
    galleryData: [
      "images/person1.png",
      "images/person2.png",
      "images/person3.png"
    ],
    tabs: [
        { text: "user", icon: "user" },
        { text: "comment", icon: "comment" },
        { text: "find", icon: "find" },
    ],
    selectedTab: ko.observable(0)
```

};

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should use option "html" instead "content" ([in accordance with the documentation](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Widgets/dxTabs/Configuration/#dataSource)).

Comment: `html` refers to the item element (the menu button), not the content of the tab.